# Ubuntu19.10 - Shutdown/Reboot hangs for about 90 sec

Tags: shutdown, 19.10, reboot, dmesg

Since at some point, this has begun. Before that, shutdown was so fast.
I've been searching to get some clue about a week, but wasn't lucky.

Following the popular method from https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Debugging/#index2h1,

Nowadays, I always get shutdown log by dmesg like below.

```
[Tue Feb 25 00:00:03 2020] systemd-journald[465]: systemd-journald stopped as pid 465
[Tue Feb 25 00:00:03 2020] systemd-journald[465]: Journal effective settings seal=no compress=yes compress_threshold_bytes=512B
[Tue Feb 25 00:01:33 2020] systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGKILL to remaining processes...
[Tue Feb 25 00:01:33 2020] systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGKILL to PID 2259 (crond).
```

And the log from 'journalctl -b -1' is like below.

```
Feb 25 00:00:03 dsk*** systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Releasing resources.
Feb 25 00:00:03 dsk*** systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Releasing all stored fds
Feb 25 00:00:03 dsk*** systemd-shutdown[1]: Found cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified, unified hierarchy for systemd controller
Feb 25 00:00:03 dsk*** systemd-shutdown[1]: Successfully forked off '(sd-sync)' as PID 9977.
Feb 25 00:00:03 dsk*** systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
Feb 25 00:00:03 dsk*** systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
Feb 25 00:00:03 dsk*** dnsmasq[1128]: exiting on receipt of SIGTERM
Feb 25 00:00:03 dsk*** systemd-journald[465]: Journal stopped
```

It looks to me,
systemd-journald finishes w/o any problem.
But I have no idea what's going on between 00:03 ~ 01:33.

Is there other log file for me to look into it?

Btw, I have a bit of doubt on Virtualbox. Though I'm no sure, since I installed virtualbox from its ppa I feel like this happening's begun.
At that time, shutdown time was way longer than 90s. Recently I purged them out, they left me 90s' delay.....

=========================================================================
Thanks, heynnema.

I followed your suggestion, so I did look into the messages on the display while shuttingdown.
[Image: Screen hangs for 90 sec. like this. Everything looks OK.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoERZ.jpg)
And, just right before physical power-off, one sentence came and gone too quick to be noticed.
So I recorded its video, and that was,

> [****]: /usr/lib/systemd/system-shutdown/fwupd.shutdown failed with exit status 2.

Comment: Shortly after issuing the shutdown command, hit the ESC key, and you should see a lot of scrolling text, showing what's going on. Look for a pause, and note what it says on the last line(s), or look for something in RED, to help determine why it's so slow. Report back.

Comment: 'fwupd.shutdown failure' seems to be issue recently, but also seems that no one reported system-hang or delay from it.
I guess this might not be my 90s delay's cause, rather, something between.....

Comment: Look for more info `grep -i fwupd /var/log/syslog*`. It's trying to update some device with new firmware and it's failing. Do you have a Logitech Unifying receiver?

Comment: No, I don't have any wireless KBD or mice. Anyway, long story short, I found the cause and removed it. It turned out fwupd wasn't the cause, because the shutdown-hang was still there even after I purged fwupd pkg out.....

Comment: Review the syslog, using my prior command example, and try to identify what device is needing to update its firmware.

Comment: You don't want to remove fwupd. Please reinstall it. Continue to check for other reasons for your shutdown delay. What was the cause that you found?

Comment: Oh, of course, I've already reinstalled it.

Answer (score 0):

What I had found at the boot log additionally,

```
libvirt-guests.sh[****]: Running guests on default URI: no running guests.
```

So, I did disable libvirt-guests.service forcedly, following the method from
[Ubuntu 16.04 libvirt-guests.sh [6917] - running guests on default URI: no running guests](https://askubuntu.com/questions/925696/ubuntu-16-04-libvirt-guests-sh-6917-running-guests-on-default-uri-no-runnin).

Shutdown-delay has gone after the next boot.
However, this is not quite the exact solution but just a temporary workaround for the delayless-shutdown(or reboot).